# ejercicio de css shake

Tags: css, animación

Me piden hacer el siguiente ejercicio en el sitio de acamica:

**Aplicar sólo lo necesario para que shake-rotate reaccione ante :hover en el elemento .**

El código inicial es:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Shake</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    
  <style>
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20vh 50px;
  }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Shake</h1>
  
  <div></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shake</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 20vh 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Shake</h1>

  <div class="shake-rotate shake-constant--hover"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Pero creo que puse cosas de más porque me da el error:

> Logic error
>
> El elemento div debería tener definida una clase con las propiedades requeridas.

¿Existe alguna forma más breve usando al librería que me permita pasar el ejercicio?¿Qué modificaciones debo de aplicar?

Comment: Deja únicamente la clase `shake-rotate` en el DIV; la animación se activa por sí sola al hacer  `hover`

Comment: Efectivamente @JheymanMejia por favor agrega tu respuesta

Comment: Listo @RuslanLopez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de quitar la compresión de la hoja de estilos `.min.css` con una [herramienta online](https://unminify.com/) pude visualizar de mejor manera el código, existe el elemento `.shake-rotate:hover` con los atributos que trae de igual manera la clase `.shake-constant`por ello sobra su uso en el ejercicio.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shake</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: 20vh 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Shake</h1>

  <div class="shake-rotate"></div>

</body>

</html>
```